# Javascript get method and airtable

Tags: javascript, airtable

Hye i am having a little trouble again i am supposed to put a list of questions in airtable and then print them to my screen but i am working with a fetch reqeust en then e method of get but i have the feeling like my empty variable aren't being filled with my questions

its in javascript btw :

here's my code :

```
; (function (){

    window.addEventListener('load', function(){

        document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(){
                window.location.href = 'vragenlijst2.html';
            })


            let vrg1 = document.getElementById('1vraag');
            let vrg2 =document.getElementById('2vraag');
            let vrg3 = document.getElementById('3vraag');
            let vrg4 = document.getElementById('4vraag');
            let vrg5 = document.getElementById('5vraag');
            let vrg6 = document.getElementById('6vraag');
            let vrg7 = document.getElementById('7vraag');
            let vrg8 = document.getElementById('8vraag');
            let vrg9 = document.getElementById('9vraag');
            let vrg10 = document.getElementById('10vraag');

            let Vragenlijst_id = 1;

            let getData = function(){
                fetch('https://api.airtable.com/v0/appojP2iMG4i3P61S/EDBL', {
                     method: 'GET',
                     headers: {
                         'Authorization' : 'Bearer keyDhD8sLGjcEuA4K'
                     }
                })

                .then(Response => Response.json())
                .then(JSON => {

                    console.log(JSON)

                    for(let index = 0; index < JSON.records.length; index++){
                        let Qstn = JSON.records[index];

                        if(Vragenlijst_id === Qstn.fields.vragenlijst){
                            let vrg1_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag1;
                            let vrg2_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag2;
                            let vrg3_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag3;
                            let vrg4_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag4;
                            let vrg5_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag5;
                            let vrg6_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag6;
                            let vrg7_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag7;
                            let vrg8_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag8;
                            let vrg9_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag9;
                            let vrg10_db = Qstn.fields.Vraag10;




                            vrg1 = vrg1_db;
                            vrg2 = vrg2_db;
                            vrg3 = vrg3_db;
                            vrg4 = vrg4_db;
                            vrg5 = vrg5_db;
                            vrg6 = vrg6_db;
                            vrg7 = vrg7_db;
                            vrg8 = vrg8_db;
                            vrg9 = vrg9_db
                            vrg10 = vrg10_db;

                            console.log(vrg1);
                        }
                    }
                })

            }

            getData();


            function create (){
                let par = document.createElement('p');
                par.innerHTML = vrg1;
                document.getElementById('1vraag').appendChild(par);
            }

            document.getElementById('1vraag').innerHTML = create()
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, could you please restrain it to the relevent part.

Comment: Consider using arrays to reduce redundant codes. I like your profile picture btw.